# Simple Interconnect circuit to simulate crosstalk in ltspice

Tags: ltspice, interconnect, crosstalk

I want to implement a very simple interconnect circuit to simulate crosstalk in ltspice because I am new to this area of crosstalk. Where can I find such a design? I have searched in the net but all the circuits seem complex and they are from different research papers.If anyone suggest me or give me a simple circuit to simulate crosstalk in ltspice then it would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: What sort of interconnect circuit do you mean? Typically, crosstalk is the result of parasitic capacitance, inductive coupling, or even resistance between two nodes, which is easily simulated.

Comment: cross coupling capacitance or parasitic capacitance would be preferable.

Comment: Well, you know what you want, so simulating it should be easy. What exactly is your question?

Comment: How do I design a simple crosstalk circuit in ltspice that simulates crosstalk due to cross coupling capacitance? I am looking for a sample design.

Comment: Add a capacitor between your signals, for a start. From there you can create progressively more complicated equivalent circuits.

Comment: How can I monitor for crosstalk? Suppose I have given two transmission lines and A capacitor between them, What do I use as their drivers for a start?

Comment: Draw a circuit comprising two analogue channels. To do this you have to decide what the analogue channels represent - we can't do this for you - you have to come up with a circuit first then state how close the channels may be to each other so that some meaningful cross talk "amount" can be assigned. You have to decide whether the signals are differential or single ended and what sort of cable they run down. Nobody is going to do a 70 page math essay covering every possible type of circuit that can be affected by cross-talk - you have to set the scenario.